# How do I copy the results of a calculation without copying the formula behind it? Open Office Calc

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice

How do I copy and paste only the results of a calculation without copying the formula behind it? I'm learning to use Open Office Calc. I remember other spreadsheets that had a values function, or simply a menu choice to paste values instead of the formulas, but this idea seems to be missing from Open Office, or called by some other name. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 12):

Use `Edit-->Copy` then `Edit-->Paste Special` (or `Copy` and `Paste Special...` from the context (right-click) menu).

In the dialog uncheck paste all, check numbers and uncheck formulas.

This is in every version of OO/LO, that I've used.